# Who are the witnesses in a court hearing?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> **Among the witnesses called by petitioner were Mr. Allen; Ms. Farrow**; Dr. Susan Coates, a clinical psychologist who treated Satchel; Dr. Nancy Schultz, a clinical psychologist who treated Dylan; and Dr. David Brodzinsky, a clinical psychologist who spoke with Dylan and Moses pursuant to his assignment in a related Surrogate’s Court proceeding.

[image: an image of the typewritten transcript quoted above]

My question is: Mr. Allen is the Petitioner and the witnesses called by petitioner at the same time?

[image: Another image of a different portion of (presumably) the same transcript as above. It says (all caps as in original): "SUPREME COURT : NEW YORK COUNTY INDIVIDUAL ASSIGNMENT PART 6 -- SU24A -- WOODY ALLEN, Petitioner, -against- MARIA VILLIERS FARROW, also known as MIA FARROW, Respondent. -- Index No. 68738/92"]

Comment: I have no idea but that's what the document you are quoting is claiming, yes. What's your question? As far as I can tell the only thing you are asking is answered right there in plain English.

Comment: Yes, they are two of the five witnesses listed in that sentence.

Comment: My question is: Mr. Allen is the Petitioner and the witnesses called by petitioner at the same time?

Comment: @user25049 Yes. More probably Mr. Allen's attorney (e.g. representative) was writing as Petitioner.

Comment: FYI: The witnesses en masse to whom you refer are "witnesses for the defense." In other words, what they had to say under questioning by the defense attorney could--the attorney hopes--exonerate his client. Ms. Farrow's own lawyer would undoubtedly call "witnesses for the prosecution" in hopes of convicting the defendant of whatever he was charged with. Don

Answer (score 2):

The "witnesses called by petitioner" **include, but are not limited to**, Allen; Farrow; Susan Coates; Nancy Schultz; and Dr. David Brodzinsky.

If the confusion is caused by the use of semi-colons, please keep in mind that the writing is *legalese*, which is a style unto itself, often confusing (sometimes purposefully, but not in this case.

Witnesses are anyone called to the stand, regardless of who the petitioner is. In cases of child abuse, the petitioner is usually either a district attorney, or a social services worker petitioning on behalf of the child.

Comment: In this case, the petitioner is Mr. Allen.

Comment: @user25049 - then this must have been a custody case.

Comment: yes, this is a custody case.

Comment: The semicolons are not legalese but an entirely ordinary way of separating the items in a list when those items themselves contain commas.